# insert inserted id to another table

Tags: postgresql, trigger, foreign-key, null

Here's the scenario:

```
create table a (
 id serial primary key,
 val text
);

create table b (
 id serial primary key,
 a_id integer references a(id)
);

create rule a_inserted as on insert to a do also insert into b (a_id) values (new.id);
```

I'm trying to create a record in b referencing to a on insertion to a table, but what I get is that new.id is null, as it's automatically generated from sequence. I also tried it with trigger, that is launched `AFTER` insert `FOR EACH ROW` on a table, but result was the same. Any way to work this out?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739661/read-and-write-autoincrement-values-from-trigger

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize the `returning` keyword which will return the value of the created serial column. If you wrap you Insert in a `With` expression, you can then access the returned id and insert into the second table.

```
WITH getval(id) as
    (INSERT INTO table_a (some_col) VALUES (some_val) RETURNING id) 
INSERT into table_b (id) SELECT id from getval;
```

where id is the value of the serial resulting from the insert into table a. More in [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-insert.html), though it is a somewhat hidden feature.

Note, you can also use `returning *` to return the entire updated row, not just the serial column, should you need it.

Answer (score 0):

in MySQL you can create a trigger. I tried on my db and it works like a champ.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_id_on_b AFTER INSERT ON a 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO b SET a_id = NEW.id; 

INSERT INTO a VALUES(148,'test 1'); 

SELECT * FROM b;
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the OP's issue because it's likely caused by `serial`.

Comment: How does this solve anything?